# Using $provide and $q

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework, angularjs-service

I'm building a mobile app using Ionic in conjunction with ngCordova.  In the hopes of developing in the browser as much as possible I want to override the ngCordova methods to return mock responses (since they depend on device features) using `$provide` in the config block of my app.js.

Something like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide) {

    if(!window.cordova) {
        $provide.value('$cordovaCapture', {
            captureImage: function() {
                return {
                    end: 0,
                    fullPath: "http://static2.shop033.com/resources/18/160536/picture/A1/85135265.jpg",
                    lastModified: null,
                    lastModifiedDate: 1412269066000,
                    localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/temporary/device-specific-file.jpg",
                    name: "photo_013.jpg",
                    size: 440614,
                    start: 0,
                    type: "image/jpeg"
                }
            }
        });
    }

}
```

However, the ngCordova `captureImage` method returns a promise, and I can't simulate a promise with `$q` due to the fact that you can't inject `$q` in the `.config` block.

Is there a different place that I can use `$provide` to override these services in conjunction with `$q`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a factory instead of a value to have injections.

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide) {

    if(!window.cordova) {
        $provide.factory('$cordovaCapture', function($q){
            return {
                captureImage: function() {
                    // Use $q here 
                    return {
                        end: 0,
                        fullPath: "http://static2.shop033.com/resources/18/160536/picture/A1/85135265.jpg",
                        lastModified: null,
                        lastModifiedDate: 1412269066000,
                        localURL: "cdvfile://localhost/temporary/device-specific-file.jpg",
                        name: "photo_013.jpg",
                        size: 440614,
                        start: 0,
                        type: "image/jpeg"
                    };
                }
            };
        });
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is use the **[`$provide.decorator()`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/auto/service/$provide#decorator)**. As defined in the documentation:

> A service decorator intercepts the creation of a service, allowing it
>   to **override or modify the behaviour** of the service. The object
>   returned by the decorator may be the original service, or a new
>   service object which replaces or wraps and delegates to the original
>   service.

The code should be something like this:

```
.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $provide) {

    if(!window.cordova) {
        $provide.decorator('$cordovaCapture', ['$delegate', '$q', function($delegate, $q) {

            var createResolver = function(mockupOptions) {
                return function(options) {
                    var deferred = $q.defer();
                    deferred.resolve(mockupOptions);
                    return deferred.promise;
                };
            };

            $delegate.captureAudio = createResolver({
                // captureAudio default options
            });

            $delegate.captureImage = createResolver({
                // captureImage default options
            });

            $delegate.captureVideo = createResolver({
                // captureVideo default options
            });

            return $delegate;
        });
    }

};
```

One more thing, the `$delegate` parameter is actually an injected instance of the original service, which is the `$cordovaCapture` in the example above.

Comment: Does calling to decorate a service fail if the service does not exist? If he is running in cordova there will be other services than if he is running in a browser. That's why I proposed a conditional service add as opposed to conditional service modification.